# Crear Histograma en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una arreglo con estos elementos

```
 int[] myArray = {1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1};
```

Y necesito crear un histograma que me de como resultado

```
1: *****
2: **
3: **
4:
5: *
```

Estoy tratando de usar algo parecido en codigo JS pero hay cosas que aun no entiendo

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,1,3,3,1,2,1,5,1};
const CantNum = {}

for (let i = 1; i <= Math.max(...myArray) ; i++){ // <-- de 1 a 8 con los intermedios

      CantNum[i] = ""; 

  }

  myArray.forEach(e=>CantNum[e] += "*"); // <-- Agregamos un * por cada aparición

  console.log(CantNum);
```

Comment: por cada numero repetido agregarle un asterisco como mostre arriba , nunca había visto esto si que estoy nulo conocimiento de esto

Comment: enfocada ala tarea

Comment: si como dije tengo algo parecido en js que me funciono pero como la sintaxis de c# es diferente no encontré como adaptarlo

Comment: pero bueno gracias igual bro

Comment: Siempre será más fácil si incluyes tu intento en C#

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que intentaste o investigaste Andres, agrega la información de lo que requieres en el cuerpo de tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El equivalente a ese código javascript en C# es el siguiente

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1 };
    Dictionary<int, string> CantNum = new Dictionary<int, string>();  // const CantNum = { }
    for (int i=1;i <= myArray.Max() ;i++) // myArray.Max() por Math.max(...myArray)
    {
        CantNum.Add(i, ""); // CantNum[i] = "";
    }
           
    foreach (var e in myArray) //myArray.forEach(e => CantNum[e] += "*")
    {
        CantNum[e] += "*";
    }

    //imprimir
    foreach (var item in CantNum)  //console.log(CantNum);
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " : " + item.Value);
    }
}
```

Las diferencias principales (además de los tipos de datos que debes agregar), son:

- En javascript un objeto `{}` puede usarse a modo de diccionario que es lo que tu estabas haciendo. En C# debes declarar una estructura del tipo `Dictionary<int,string>` donde `int` indica que la clave será del tipo entero y `string` indica que lo guardado será un string
- Luego para imprimir en consola, en C# debes recorrer la lista e imprimir uno a uno

El resto creo que es bastante igual, de toda maneras te dejé en los comentarios las equivalencias al javascript

Comment: Si me falta un montón por aprender, antes de esto no sabia ni lo que era un histograma, gracias como siempre por tu tiempo y ayuda

Comment: @AndresEdu De nada estimado, la verdad que luego de analizar lo que te faltaba, me di cuenta que los cambios eran bastante menores entre el algoritmo en JS y en C#. Espero que te haya servido para notar las diferencias. Saludos

Comment: si lo vuelvo a repetir son cosas que sirven en el futuro pueden ser detalles pequeños pero todo sirve para seguir aprendiendo en esto de la programación